# Writing on the same line in FORTRAN

Tags: fortran

In Fortran, each time one uses `WRITE` a new line is produced. In order to control the working of a program that is being executed, I would like to write on screen the current value of a variable, but always on the same line (erasing the previous value and starting at the beginning of the line). That is, something like

```
 1    CONTINUE
      "update the value of a"
      WRITE(*,*) a
      BACKSPACE "screen"
      GOTO 1
```

Something like `WRITE(*,*,ADVANCE='NO')` (incorrect anyway) is not quite what I
need: this would write all the values of `a` one after another on a very long
line.

Comment: Pretty sure that `BACKSPACE` does **not** do what you seem to think it does.

Answer (score 9):

A trick that I was shown for what you want is as follows

```
do l=1,lmax
   ...update a...
   write(*,'(1a1,<type>,$)') char(13), a
enddo
```

where `<type>` is your format specifier for `a` (i.e., `i0` for integer).

The key is the `char(13)`, which is the carriage return, and the `$` in the format descriptor. I really don't know if there is a name for `$`, I just know that it works for displaying on the screen--for output to file you get an `a` on each line.

Comment: Note the $ descriptor is not in the standard language.

Comment: I presumed it was not standard, but it works for me with ifort 11+ and gfortran 4.6 & 4.7.

Comment: advance=no is the 'standard' replacement for the $.  Also the solution is dependent on your terminal type, if this answer isn't working come back and tell us what terminal you are running,